# Identify all templates in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to get a list of all the sitecore templates and/or possibly all the content pages, modules. Wondering if there a quick way in Sitecore to identify all the templates that have been defined? need this just for the numbers

Comment: Do you want to get this list by code?

Comment: possible to get without coding?

Comment: Not sure. Do you need also Sitecore native templates or only templates which were defined by user?

Answer (score 2):

You can search a folder and apply filters to narrow the items that the search returns which will give you a count of the items that match the filters that you've defined.

From the Content Editor:

1. Select the Templates folder: `/sitecore/templates`
2. Select the Search tab in the right pane
3. Click on the "More Search Options" arrow on the left side of the search box
4. Click Search Filters
5. Click Search by template

[image: filter the search by Template]

6. A filter box will show up in the search box. Start typing to get an autocomplete list. Select the template you would like to filter by.

[image: Select the template to filter by]

7. The search will now filter the results by the template that you selected.

[image: filtered search input]

Multiple filters can be applied to a search. Apply the necessary filters to get the counts that you require.